# Reset default file encoding to UTF-8 in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: file, visual-studio-2013, encoding, utf-8, default

Tools used:
Visual Studio Professional 2013
Team Foundation Server 2013

Problem:
I have a solution under source control containing a project with some SSIS packages. The encoding of all the *.dtsx files is UTF-8. Now all of a sudden whenever I create a new package and want to save it I get a message from Visual Studio (Source Control) that the file encoding has changed. In Source Control Explorer I can see that the encoding of the new *.dtsx file is windows 1252 and I can manually set it to UTF-8.

I've tried to change my windows locale to english, I also checked Tools => Options => Environment => Document to save in Unicode if saving in Codepage is not possible. All of this did not work: still each new SSIS package is created in windows 1252 encoding. Does anybody know how to reset the default to UTF-8 ?

Comment: The File > Advanced Save Options menu item sets the default.

Comment: Unfortunately the Advanced Save Options menu item doesn't show up. The Microsoft documentation says this option doesn't show up in certain development settings and recommends to reset via Tools/Import and Export settings. However this did not solve the issue in my case. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: I also looked up Microsoft documentation for showing up this dialog - the way to go is via Tools/Customize. Unfortunately the Advanced Save Options menu item shows up only on certain project types - and this is not the case in SSIS projects and this is where I'm having the issue. Any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way to accomplish this.  I did, however, find a free third-party extension – [Fix File Encoding](https://vlasovstudio.com/fix-file-encoding/) that will prevent Visual Studio from changing files from UTF-8 encoding, or from adding BOM to that encoding.